# Trigger jupyter notebook save

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook that I opened on a remote computer (with the kernel also running on that remote computer). I have also opened the notebook on my local computer (connecting to the remote kernel) but there have been changes to the notebook on the remote that haven't been saved.

Is there a way to trigger the remote computer to save the notebook, e.g., by sshing in and issuing some command?

Comment: If there are changes and it is still running, it should autosave within two minutes (unless you disabled this). If it's not autosaving for some reason, you would need to get access to the browser it's open in to save it.

Answer (score 2):

It can be trigged by JavaScript.

`IPython.notebook.save_notebook();`

Comment: Jupyter.notebook.save_notebook();